# Append the text using sed

Tags: sed, fstab

I'm working on a script used for post installation of Centos/Redhat. To make filesystem more secure i want to add few parameters like `nosuid,noexec` for tmpfs.

In Redhat 6 this line is at line number 12 in fstab. I could easily edit file using command

```
# sed '12s/defaults/&,noexec/' /etc/fstab
```

it will add `noexec` after defaults but i want it to be more dynamic , maybe in RHEL 7 it is not on Line number 10.

So I want it to search for line starting with `tmpfs` and add the text after defaults. Tried many times but kept failing. Any suggestions how to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Just mark the line containing the `tmpfs` entry and do an append of the required option after "default"

```
sed '/^tmpfs/{s/defaults/&,noexec/}' /etc/fstab
```

Add the `-i` option if the file change looks expected on GNU `sed` and `-i''` for `sed` on FreeBSD